# How do I use sockets to autosynchronize 2 clients that are connected to a server in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server, client

I currently am trying to use websockets in order to auto-synchronize multiple clients that are connected to the same spring boot server.
I added the following dependencies to be able to use sockets:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
```

And I am using this config file for websockets:

WebSocketConfig.java

```
package server;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    /**
     * The method will be used to carry any messages that the server received
     * back to the client
     * @param config the configuration file that the method will use
     */
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    /**
     * The method is used to enable spring's STOMP support
     * @param registry the registry file that the method will use
     */
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

MessageController.java

```
package server;

import commons.Collection;
import commons.Message;
import commons.ResponseMessage;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils;

@Controller
public class MessageController {

    /**
     * @param collection the message that is being transmitted
     * @return the message that was received
     * @throws InterruptedException an exception which happens when the process is interrupted
     */
    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public Collection getMessage(final Collection collection) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("received message");
        return new Collection(collection.getId(), collection.getName(), collection.getBoardId(), collection.getCards());
    }

}
```

Collection.java

```
package commons;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "collections")
public class Collection {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;


    @Column(name = "board_id")
    private Long boardId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "collectionId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * the collection constructor
     * @param id the id used by database
     * @param name the name of the collection
     * @param boardId the board it is on
     * @param cards the list of cards
     */
    public Collection(Long id, String name, Long boardId, List<Card> cards) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.boardId = boardId;
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the name of the collection
     * @return String - the name of the collection
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * get the board id
     * @return board id
     */
    public Long getBoardId() {
        return boardId;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the list of cards
     * @return List<Card> - list of all cards present in the
     */
    public List<Card> getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    /**
     * get the id
     * @return id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

So currently the problem that I have is that none of these files actually do anything! So when I create a collection on one client, which involves sending it to the server, it is not reflected on any other client unless I update it with another action! Could it be because I didn't implement the Message controller well? Or is it that I need to add something on the client side to make it listen to some kind of input?

All the info that I used was taken from these websites:

https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/EnableWebSocketMessageBroker.html

https://guttikondaparthasai.medium.com/websocket-using-spring-boot-java-b95eb142f020

And also some love from chatgpt

Comment: ...wondering if that has any relevance to the  jconsole in the SDK folder that has a network settings guii interface , it is used by spring to proxy through.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant are you talking about some specific file? Because there is no jconsole file in the project, let alone an SDK folder.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant sorry for being so inconsistent about it, but I just found out the correct way of doing this, and it involves a completely different approach, which is why I had to make such a huge edit to my post.

Comment: No I'm just completely wrong about it being a spring issue. What do you mean asynchronize two clients between a server, asynchronous behaviour generally means read and write with the network node at the same time without either the read or the write being stopped and requires both the server and the client delegating an asynchronous type connection. Did you mean "broadcast" simultaneous to the clients.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant yes. That should be what I need. Because as far as I know, broadcast means that once the server receives input from one server, it "broadcasts" the input to all the other active clients, right? If so, then yes, that's what I need.

Comment: "broadcast" in what context, server to all network "registered" network machines (fixed hardware), or all relevant software registered over any network allowed (alike login). So does the software have the reason for being connected or or is it a rigid listening and send receive tx tx software. By this point describing the purpose of the activity and software would greatly help anyone reading this thread .

Comment: Just show you these.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html      https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html

Comment: @SamuelMarchant sorry if I misunderstood what you meant by this, but I believe that it would be "all relevant software registered oven any network" because the project will function to a similar way a chat app would work. Meaning that the reason for the clients to be connected is that it is necessary for the function of the app, since all the clients will be using 1 server, and if 1 client changes something, it has to be visible on all other clients.

Comment: chat app, wish I'd asked what I suspected two of my  posts before! The difference is the network "address route hops" over IP routes can be different during the request for parts of the info of a stream requiring packet numbering, but as far as I know that is what http protocol is for to handle.  Good to "read the info".   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html        and   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html

Comment: Asynchronous would require stateful http. But not clear if simply good management by verification from each client for the server client management indexing allows ordinary http requests to do the job. Non asynchronous would be less congestive. Each client asking every 10 seconds (java.util.Timer)with their last message received number could have a response update. A combination of webserver, message store and indexing policy over http would in my mind operate better as the base of the principals than thereabout a server and sockets being written too.

Comment: If you want a better distributive understanding of "sockets" and stateful stateless http and asynchronous, AJAX connections show that asynchronous over http has little use, but extremely important for its one or two uses such as address bar searches as the user types the keyboard. Whereas if it were machine to machine in a network, either broadcast address or asynchronous socket connection direct connect for software app to corresponding server socket and software is a different point.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to just add the standard files that are needed on the client side for this to work, something along the lines of:

```
    StompSession session = connect("ws://localhost:8080/websocket");

    private StompSession connect(String url) {
        var client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        var stomp = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stomp.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        try {
            return stomp.connect(url, new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {}).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    public <T> void registerForCollections(String dest, Class<T> type, Consumer<T> consumer) {
        session.subscribe(dest, new StompFrameHandler() {
            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                return type;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                consumer.accept((T) payload);
            }
        });
    }

    public void send(String dest, Object o) {
        System.out.println(session);
        session.
```

And then just use the registerForCollections method to subscribe the server side.

But that is not enough since I needed a lot of apis for that to work, but that is not a part of my question, so I won't be including that in here.